# r - filter through all variables in a dataframe for at least two of them having same value

Tags: r, filter

Trying to implement a filter that will work through all of the variables in a dataframe with the condition being: if the values in at least two variables are the same remove. For example if I make this dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(2,3,4)

df <- expand.grid(rep(list(a), length(a)))
```

In this case we have only three variables: `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3` and the filter can be written like this:

```
df %>% filter(!(Var1 == Var2 | Var2 == Var3 | Var1 == Var3))
```

can filtering like this be applied on n number of variables in a dataframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of unique values in a row and remove rows where ncol < nunique

```
nunique <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))

df <- df[nunique == ncol(df), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `anyDuplicated`

```
df[!apply(df, 1, anyDuplicated),]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap_lgl(df, ~ !anyDuplicated(c(...))) %>% 
          magrittr::extract(df, ., )
```